# JQuery автозаполнения полей

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Есть функция для автозаполнения полей

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function ac(id) {
    $('#' + id + '').autocomplete("search.php?a=" + id + '');
}

$(".mete").click(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");  
  ac(id);
});

});
```

HTML код

```
<input class="mete" id="39" name="chars[39]" value="" type="text">
<a href="#" class="meteall" id="39" >все варианты</a><br>
<input class="mete" id="40" name="chars[40]" value="" type="text">
<a href="#" class="meteall" id="40" >все варианты</a>
```

Хочу дописать функцию чтобы при клике по ссылке "все варианты"  выводились все варианты.
как я понял из мануала надо использовать метод .autocomplete("search", "");
но пока ни чего не получается :)

Comment: Пробую так, но не работает. что не так ? 

    function ac1(id) {
        $('#' + id + '').autocomplete("search.php?a=" + id + '');
        $('#' + id + '').autocomplete("search", "");
    }

    $(".meteall").click(function () {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");  
      ac1(id);
    });

Answer (score 1):

Сам не пользовался, но могу подсказать хороший мануал по твоей теме: [jQuery autocomplete](http://habrahabr.ru/post/74713/)